# Incomprehensible For Loop Icarus Verilog

Tags: verilog, test-bench, icarus

I am trying to follow the basic example provided here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13CzlujAayc&list=PLUtfVcb-iqn8ff92DJ0SZqwsX4W1s_oab&index=17

Here is my exact code

maj3.v

```
module maj3(Out, A, B, C);
    input A, B, C;
    output Out;

    wire AB, BC, AC;

        and(AB, A, B);
    and(BC, B, C);
    and(AC, A, C);

    or(Out, AB, BC, AC);

endmodule
```

testbench.v

```
module maj3_tb;

    reg a, b, c;
    wire out;

    maj3 DUT1(out, a, b, c);

    initial begin
        for (int i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
            #5 {a,b,c} = i;
        end
    end

    initial begin
        $monitor(a,b,c,out);
    end

endmodule
```

I am trying to compile with Icarus Verilog, but I am getting this error

> ```
> testbench.v:9: syntax error
> testbench.v:9: error: Incomprehensible for loop.
> ```

I have looked through my code a few times and I believe I have the same exact lines the lecturer has and I am using the same compiler. The only difference is that his is operating in a browser, whereas mine is in the Ubuntu terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to look closely, but it looks like my default version was not matching his.

[image]

I reran the compile command with the same flags

> iverilog -Wall -g2012 -o maj3_test testbench.v maj3.v

and it compiled fine. Not sure what the default version is or why it did not compile with that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

*Try this format. It solved the error.*

Convert int to integer and declare it above "initial begin".

```
integer i;
initial begin
for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
        #5;
        {a,b,c} = i;
    end
end
```